# Image not found when using the stenciljs bundle

Tags: stencils

I have this stenciljs component which uses an svg images like this:

```
...
return (
  <button>
    <img src="../../assets/icon.svg"/>
    <slot/>
  </button>
);
...
```

My folder structure is

```
src/
    assets/
           icon.svg
    components/
              button/
                     button.tsx
```

Now, when I do `stencil build` it creates the `dist` folder with everything in it.

I copy the dist folder into my site, which has the following structure:

```
my-web/
       index.html
       bundle/
              <content from dist>
```

And inside the index.html I load the bundle

```
<script src="/bundle/my-componets.js"></script>
```

This works as expected but the asset is loaded from `/assets/icon.svg` which does not exist (404). Any suggestions what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this I guess.

First:
Take a look at https://stenciljs.com/docs/config#copy.
Using this config setting you can copy your assets (.svg files & whatever) to your dist folder. You can also specify a destination for the files to be copied to, like:

```
copy: [
    { src: "../path/to/the/files", dest: "./path/to/paste/the/files" }
  ],
```

Second:
Import the asset to the JS of your component. You'll need a Rollup Plugin to handle the import (example: rollup-plugin-svg-to-jsx - but there are others). After setting this plugin up, you can just do:

```
import * as Icon from "path/to/your/svg"

...

return (
  <button>
    <Icon />
    <slot />
  </button>
);
```

The first one will keep your JS bundle a little smaller and load the Icon.svg file when you place the button somewhere on the page.
The second one will bundle the svg into your JS and load together with your JS - so there is no Button without the Icon at any times.

Answer (score 1):

From what you intend to do, I understand your goal is to have fully runnable standalone application inside `./dist` after build.All sourcefiles which are needed to run the application should be placed there.

This means you will need to create a copy of the sourcefiles (staticfiles) into the distribution folder in the way `my-web/assets/icon.svg` in order for the application to locate and access it.

Comment: Ok, this means that my site needs to include `./dist` and also include `assets` in the root. Ideally I would somehow include the assets inside `dist` so I don't have to do both. Is that possible?